# Javascript order select list by text alphe and not value

Tags: javascript, select, alpha

My JS call my data, it's very well working to build a dynamic 3 levels select option menu

I make a change of the text of the category select option and it's working too .. now I have to re-ordered ma select list, not on the option value but with an alpha text order.

My JS :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
oXmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
 oXmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }

 function selectManufacturer(id) {
 document.getElementById('subcategory').innerHTML = "";
 oXmlhttp.open('POST',"recherche-listesderoulantes-resultats.php");
 oXmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (oXmlhttp.readyState==4 && oXmlhttp.status == 200) {
 leselect = oXmlhttp.responseText;
 document.getElementById('category').innerHTML = leselect;
 }


 var strMessage1 = document.getElementById("category") ;
 strMessage1.innerHTML = strMessage1.innerHTML
 .replace('option   value="13446">XXXXX</option>','<option value="13446">NEW TEXT 1</option>')
 .replace('option value="13449">YYYYY</option>','<option value="13449">NEW TEXT 2</option>');
 }
  oXmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 var data = 'q=m&id='+id;
 oXmlhttp.send (data);
 }
 function selectCategory(manufacturer,category) {
 oXmlhttp.open('POST',"recherche-listesderoulantes-resultats.php");
 oXmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (oXmlhttp.readyState==4 && oXmlhttp.status == 200) {
 leselect = oXmlhttp.responseText;
 document.getElementById('subcategory').innerHTML = leselect;
 }
 }
 oXmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 var data = 'q=c&manufacturer='+manufacturer+'&id='+category;
 oXmlhttp.send (data);
```

MY HTML

```
 <form method="get" action="recherche-listesderoulantes-resultats.php">
  <select style="width: 80%" id="manufacturers_id" name="manufacturers_id" onchange="selectManufacturer(this.value);">
 <option value='-1'>Select</option>
 <option value="1739" >Brand</option><option value="5794" >Brand 1</option>$<option      value="1753" >Brand 2</option></select>
 <div id='category' style='display:inline'>
 </div>
 <div id='subcategory' style='display:inline'>
 </div>
 </form
```

Every thing is ok still now but  I'm try to understand how I could make a new order of the category list with text alpha value and not value option after the replace var...

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot use JavaScript sort on elements, you can create an array from the text of option elements and then reset the text of the option elements as follows:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('manufacturers_id');
var asel = [];
for (var i=1; i<sel.length; i++) { //omit Select
  asel.push(sel[i].text);
}
asel.sort()
for (var j=0; j < asel.length;j++) {
    sel[j+1].text = asel[j];
    alert(sel[j+1].text);
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xv8mg663/) Note I change the Brand 1 text to Brand 3 to illustrate that the select dropdown reflects the new sorted order.